# How to show tooltip in android jetpack compose

Tags: android, tooltip, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to add a simple tooltip in my app UI for `FAB`, `IconButton`, `Menu`, etc.

[image: Example tooltip]

How to add this in **jetpack compose**?
I am familiar with how to add using XML and programmatically as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/tooltips#kotlin).

Limitations with those methods - trying to avoid XML as much as possible and for programmatic approach, there is no findViewById in compose for obvious reasons.

Refered [Jetpack Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary), [Codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics) and [Samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples).
Got nothing related to the tooltip.

Any help is appreciated.

**Note**
Not looking for any customizations, plain and simple tooltip would do.
And preferable no 3rd party libs.

**Update**
Anyone having the same requirement, please bump up this [issue created](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187098109).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official `tooltip` support yet in **Jetpack Compose**.

You could probably build something on top of `androidx.compose.ui.window.Popup(...)`

Also I'd check out [TextDelegate](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:compose/ui/ui-text/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextDelegate.kt;drc=37f0b2ec8c2709454fd031ed2d36e2c347a4377d), to measure the text in order to know where & how to position the tooltip/popup.

Answer (score 18):

**UPDATE**

Since version **[1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0)** (released on May 10, 2023), Jetpack Compose Material 3 now includes official tooltips. There are two types of them: **plain tooltips** ([`PlainTooltipBox`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#PlainTooltipBox(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.PlainTooltipState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1))) and **rich tooltips** ([`RichTooltipBox`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#RichTooltipBox(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.RichTooltipState,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material3.RichTooltipColors,kotlin.Function1))).

- [Blog post about the 1.1 release of Material Design 3 for Compose](https://material.io/blog/material-3-compose-1-1)
- [Material Design 3 overview and guidelines for Tooltips](https://m3.material.io/components/tooltips/)
- Support for tooltips was first added in version [`1.1.0-alpha05`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0-alpha05), January 11, 2023

##### Plain tooltips

Plain tooltips briefly describe a UI element. Plain tooltips are great for labeling UI elements with no text, like icon-only and field elements.

[image: Plain tooltip on an icon button]

To apply the plain tooltip to any component, wrap the component with the `PlainTooltipBox()` and add `Modifier.tooltipAnchor()` to the component’s modifier:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.PlainTooltipBox
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

PlainTooltipBox(
   tooltip = { Text("Present now") }
) {
   IconButton(
       onClick = { /* Icon button's click event */ },
       modifier = Modifier.tooltipTrigger()
   ) {
       Icon(
           imageVector = Icons.Filled.FilePresent,
           contentDescription = "Present now"
       )
   }
}
```

##### Rich tooltips

Rich tooltips are great for longer text, such as definitions or explanations. Rich tooltips provide additional context to a UI element and can include a button or hyperlink.

[image: Rich tooltip with description and text button as action]

You can have either persistent or non-persistent rich tooltips by providing the `isPersistent` parameter to `RichTooltipState()`. To dismiss persistent tooltips, you need to tap outside the tooltip area or invoke the dismiss action on the tooltip state.

Non-persistent tooltips are automatically dismissed after a short duration.

To add rich tooltips, you can use the `RichTooltipBox()` composable and modify the tooltip state to control the visibility of the tooltip.

```kotlin
val tooltipState = remember { RichTooltipState() }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
RichTooltipBox(
   title = { Text("Add others") },
   action = {
       TextButton(
           onClick = { scope.launch { tooltipState.dismiss() } }
       ) { Text("Learn More") }
   },
   text = { Text("Share this collection with friends...") },
   tooltipState = tooltipState
) {
   IconButton(
       onClick = { /* Icon button's click event */ },
       modifier = Modifier.tooltipTrigger()
   ) {
       Icon(
           imageVector = Icons.Filled.People,
           contentDescription = "Add others"
       )
   }
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**, still can be useful for manual implementation.

There was no official tooltip composable in Jetpack Compose as of October 21, 2021.

But a nice tooltip can be effectively constructed with [`androidx.compose.ui.window.Popup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Popup(androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupPositionProvider,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupProperties,kotlin.Function0)).
We can take material [DropdownMenu](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/696caaf1/compose/material/material/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/AndroidMenu.android.kt#74) implementation as a starting point.

**Result example (see source code below):**
[image: Tooltip example for AndroidX Jetpack Compose]

**How to show Tooltip on long click (usage example):**

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.ExperimentalFoundationApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.combinedClickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.ripple.rememberRipple
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
fun TooltipOnLongClickExample(onClick: () -> Unit = {}) {
  // Commonly a Tooltip can be placed in a Box with a sibling
  // that will be used as the 'anchor' for positioning.
  Box {
    val showTooltip = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // Buttons and Surfaces don't support onLongClick out of the box,
    // so use a simple Box with combinedClickable
    Box(
      modifier = Modifier
        .combinedClickable(
          interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
          indication = rememberRipple(),
          onClickLabel = "Button action description",
          role = Role.Button,
          onClick = onClick,
          onLongClick = { showTooltip.value = true },
        ),
    ) {
      Text("Click Me (will show tooltip on long click)")
    }

    Tooltip(showTooltip) {
      // Tooltip content goes here.
      Text("Tooltip Text!!")
    }
  }
}
```

**Tooltip composable source code:**

```kotlin
@file:Suppress("INVISIBLE_REFERENCE", "INVISIBLE_MEMBER")

import androidx.compose.animation.core.MutableTransitionState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloat
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.animation.core.updateTransition
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.alpha
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.takeOrElse
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.toArgb
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalDensity
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpOffset
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Popup
import androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupProperties
import androidx.core.graphics.ColorUtils
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay


/**
 * Tooltip implementation for AndroidX Jetpack Compose.
 * Based on material [DropdownMenu] implementation
 *
 * A [Tooltip] behaves similarly to a [Popup], and will use the position of the parent layout
 * to position itself on screen. Commonly a [Tooltip] will be placed in a [Box] with a sibling
 * that will be used as the 'anchor'. Note that a [Tooltip] by itself will not take up any
 * space in a layout, as the tooltip is displayed in a separate window, on top of other content.
 *
 * The [content] of a [Tooltip] will typically be [Text], as well as custom content.
 *
 * [Tooltip] changes its positioning depending on the available space, always trying to be
 * fully visible. It will try to expand horizontally, depending on layout direction, to the end of
 * its parent, then to the start of its parent, and then screen end-aligned. Vertically, it will
 * try to expand to the bottom of its parent, then from the top of its parent, and then screen
 * top-aligned. An [offset] can be provided to adjust the positioning of the menu for cases when
 * the layout bounds of its parent do not coincide with its visual bounds. Note the offset will
 * be applied in the direction in which the menu will decide to expand.
 *
 * @param expanded Whether the tooltip is currently visible to the user
 * @param offset [DpOffset] to be added to the position of the tooltip
 *
 * @see androidx.compose.material.DropdownMenu
 * @see androidx.compose.material.DropdownMenuPositionProvider
 * @see androidx.compose.ui.window.Popup
 *
 * @author Artyom Krivolapov
 */
@Composable
fun Tooltip(
  expanded: MutableState<Boolean>,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  timeoutMillis: Long = TooltipTimeout,
  backgroundColor: Color = Color.Black,
  offset: DpOffset = DpOffset(0.dp, 0.dp),
  properties: PopupProperties = PopupProperties(focusable = true),
  content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
  val expandedStates = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }
  expandedStates.targetState = expanded.value

  if (expandedStates.currentState || expandedStates.targetState) {
    if (expandedStates.isIdle) {
      LaunchedEffect(timeoutMillis, expanded) {
        delay(timeoutMillis)
        expanded.value = false
      }
    }

    Popup(
      onDismissRequest = { expanded.value = false },
      popupPositionProvider = DropdownMenuPositionProvider(offset, LocalDensity.current),
      properties = properties,
    ) {
      Box(
        // Add space for elevation shadow
        modifier = Modifier.padding(TooltipElevation),
      ) {
        TooltipContent(expandedStates, backgroundColor, modifier, content)
      }
    }
  }
}


/** @see androidx.compose.material.DropdownMenuContent */
@Composable
private fun TooltipContent(
  expandedStates: MutableTransitionState<Boolean>,
  backgroundColor: Color,
  modifier: Modifier,
  content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
  // Tooltip open/close animation.
  val transition = updateTransition(expandedStates, "Tooltip")

  val alpha by transition.animateFloat(
    label = "alpha",
    transitionSpec = {
      if (false isTransitioningTo true) {
        // Dismissed to expanded
        tween(durationMillis = InTransitionDuration)
      } else {
        // Expanded to dismissed.
        tween(durationMillis = OutTransitionDuration)
      }
    }
  ) { if (it) 1f else 0f }

  Card(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor.copy(alpha = 0.75f),
    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.contentColorFor(backgroundColor)
      .takeOrElse { backgroundColor.onColor() },
    modifier = Modifier.alpha(alpha),
    elevation = TooltipElevation,
  ) {
    val p = TooltipPadding
    Column(
      modifier = modifier
        .padding(start = p, top = p * 0.5f, end = p, bottom = p * 0.7f)
        .width(IntrinsicSize.Max),
      content = content,
    )
  }
}

private val TooltipElevation = 16.dp
private val TooltipPadding = 16.dp

// Tooltip open/close animation duration.
private const val InTransitionDuration = 64
private const val OutTransitionDuration = 240

// Default timeout before tooltip close
private const val TooltipTimeout = 2_000L - OutTransitionDuration


// Color utils

/**
 * Calculates an 'on' color for this color.
 *
 * @return [Color.Black] or [Color.White], depending on [isLightColor].
 */
fun Color.onColor(): Color {
  return if (isLightColor()) Color.Black else Color.White
}

/**
 * Calculates if this color is considered light.
 *
 * @return true or false, depending on the higher contrast between [Color.Black] and [Color.White].
 *
 */
fun Color.isLightColor(): Boolean {
  val contrastForBlack = calculateContrastFor(foreground = Color.Black)
  val contrastForWhite = calculateContrastFor(foreground = Color.White)
  return contrastForBlack > contrastForWhite
}

fun Color.calculateContrastFor(foreground: Color): Double {
  return ColorUtils.calculateContrast(foreground.toArgb(), toArgb())
}
```

Tested with AndroidX Jetpack Compose version `1.1.0-alpha06`

See a Gist with full example: 
https://gist.github.com/amal/aad53791308e6edb055f3cf61f881451

Comment: it doesn't allow custom UI

Comment: @user924 check `RichTooltipBox`, it does allow custom UI.  And my old example also allows you to change UI in any way.

Comment: Can we implement rounded shape with Triangle for tooltip with `RichTooltipBox`?

Answer (score 9):

With M3 you can use the **`PlainTooltipBox`** composable:

Something like:

```
    PlainTooltipBox(
        tooltip = { Text("Add to favorites" ) },
        contentColor = White,
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = { /* Icon button's click event */ },
            modifier = Modifier.tooltipAnchor()
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                contentDescription = "Localized Description"
            )
        }
    }
```

The Tooltip is invoked when the `anchor` is long pressed.

[image]

If you want to display the tooltip with an event click you can use:

```
    val tooltipState = remember { PlainTooltipState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    PlainTooltipBox(
        tooltip = { Text("Add to favorites" ) },
        tooltipState = tooltipState
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = { /* Icon button's click event */ },
            modifier = Modifier.tooltipAnchor()
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                contentDescription = "Localized Description"
            )
        }
    }

    Spacer(Modifier.requiredHeight(30.dp))
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { scope.launch { tooltipState.show() } }
    ) {
        Text("Display tooltip")
    }
```

Comment: How can I add tail or use composable function instead of Text? I used composable function and the background doesn't seem disappear even after giving the containerColor, contentColor to Transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to show a tooltip centered in the screen. If you don't need the triangle, just remove its row. It would be nice to add a surface to the tooltip.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WY6i.png

```
@ExperimentalComposeUiApi
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun tooltip(text: String) {

   Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Column {

                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(PaddingValues(start = 12.dp))
                    .background(
                        color = colors.xxx,
                        shape = TriangleShape(arrowPosition)
                    )
                    .width(arrowSize.width)
                    .height(arrowSize.height)
                ) {}

                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        color = colors.xxx,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 3.dp)
                    )
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
                        text = text,
                        alignment = TextAlign.Center,
                    )
                }

            }
        }
}
```

Function to draw the triangle:

```
class TriangleEdge(val position: ArrowPosition) : Shape {

override fun createOutline(
    size: Size,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
    density: Density
): Outline {

val trianglePath = Path()
trianglePath.apply {
            moveTo(x = size.width/2, y = 0f)
            lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height)
            lineTo(x = 0f, y = size.height)
        }

return Outline.Generic(path = trianglePath)
```

}

Comment: I tried to copy and paste this solution, but `TriangleShape`, `ArrowPosition`, `arrowSize` were not found. Is this for Material 2 or Material 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the answer from Luchi to have it work in the newer Jetpack Compose.

**Tooltip.kt**

```
@Composable
fun Tooltip(text: String) {
    val color = Color.Gray

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Column {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(PaddingValues(start = 12.dp))
                .background(
                    color = color,
                    shape = TriangleShape()
                )
                .width(20.dp)
                .height(10.dp)
            )

            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = color,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 6.dp)
                )
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = text,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TriangleShape.kt**

```
class TriangleShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {

        val path = Path()
        path.apply {
            moveTo(x = size.width / 2, y = 0f)
            lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height)
            lineTo(x = 0f, y = size.height)
        }

        return Outline.Generic(path = path)
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

You can customise the code further to suit your need.