# Helper on button long tap with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to display description of button when it long pressed. This is available by default in the ActionBar XML, but I want to do the same when the IconButton is clicked in Compose. I'm surprised that contentDescription only provides this information for Accessibility users.

This behavior is implemented in Google Play: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQqz1.png

The only solution I've found is to use onLongClick = { }, but I wouldn't want to use additional @Composable or Toast.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378308/how-to-show-tooltip-in-android-jetpack-compose , Check this , this will be helpful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest alpha versions of `Material3` *(Google Play uses Material 3 too)*, the feature for tooltip was added.

You can check the release notes on [Version 1.1.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0-alpha04) and [Version 1.1.0-alpha06](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0-alpha06).

As this is a new feature, still in alpha version, it doesn't have a final documentation ready, but at this moment you can use it as follows:

```kotlin
val helperSearchMessage = "Search something by name"

PlainTooltipBox(
    tooltip = { Text(text = helperSearchMessage) }
) { // content for TooltipBoxScope
    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier.tooltipAnchor(),
        onClick = { println("search button clicked") }
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
            contentDescription = helperSearchMessage
        )
    }
}
```

About `PlainTooltipBox`:

> Plain tooltip that provides a descriptive message for an anchor.

About modifier `tooltipAnchor`:

> Modifier that should be applied to the anchor composable when showing
> the tooltip after long pressing the anchor composable is desired. It
> appends a long click to the composable that this modifier is chained
> with.

Basically you will use the `tooltipAnchor()` in the composable that will activate the tooltip, this modifier will only be available to use inside of `TooltipBoxScope`.

---

We can also use the `RichTooltipBox` for more complex tooltip

> Rich text tooltip that allows the user to pass in a title, text, and
> action. Tooltips are used to provide a descriptive message for an
> anchor.

```kotlin
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val tooltipState = remember { RichTooltipState() }

RichTooltipBox(
    tooltipState = tooltipState,
    text = { Text(text = "Tooltip text (not optional)") },
    title = { Text(text = "Tooltip title (optional)") },
    action = {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    tooltipState.dismiss()
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Tooltip action (optional)")
        }
    }
) {
    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier.tooltipAnchor(),
        onClick = { println("search button clicked") }
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
            contentDescription = helperSearchMessage
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `tooltipAnchor()` has now been renamed to `tooltipTrigger()`

Comment: tooltipTrigger is also not resoved